# Extra attributes in a certificate signing request

Tags: rsa, openssl, certificates

When creating a certificate signing request, there is a part where openssl says "Please enter the following extra attributes to be sent with your certificate request". One of these is a challenge password.

Under what circumstances will this password be needed?

Comment: I _think_ this is a password that looks strangers out from actually looking at the contents of the CSR (e.g. enlisted name, state, city, emails, public keys, ...)

Comment: But this password is not used to encrypt the CSR. So I would not imagine its used to obfuscate the contents of the CSR

Comment: If you want **you can remove this prompt** (and attribute) and/or unstructuredName, and/or in principle add others but I know no sensible others to add, in the section identified by the `attributes` setting in the `[req]` section of your config file, normally `[req_attributes]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [RFC 2985](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2985#page-16):

> The challengePassword attribute type specifies a password by which an
> entity may request certificate revocation.  The interpretation of
> challenge passwords is intended to be specified by certificate issuers
> etc; no particular interpretation is required.

This has also come up over at [Information Security Stackexchange](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/77082/71460) with the TL;DR being **it's the password you set during the certificate request to share a revocation password with the CA, this however is rarely to never used in practice**, because CAs nowadays have "normal" log-in mechanisms just like any other website and use them control revocation.

Comment: This means certificate revocations are necessarily requested by the certificate owners? Otherwise any third parties would not have access to this password

Comment: @Minaj certificate revokations are _always_ issued by the CA (usually upon request of the owner or his authorized delegate). Because random _really_ should not be allowed to let certificates be revoked arbitrarily. Only image I could revoke the google certificate now...

Comment: Ohh, I was under the impression that some third party standards organisation can also request for a revocation if a certain site is found to be "crooked"

Comment: @Minaj, I guess if some organisation with enough authority asks hard enough (maybe with the power of law?) then surely they can also enforce revokation of a specific certificate, but certificates are CA's core business and as such they have to meet relieability standards and such and thus won't revoke anything without a _very good_ reason (except if the customer requests it himself)

Comment: @SEJPM I guess proving access to the private key would do the trick :)